# How to use ObjectContext with Model Builder?

Tags: entity-framework-5, dbcontext, objectcontext

Is there a way we can use ObjectContext with DbContext's ModelBuilder? We don't want to use POCO because we have customized property code that does not modify entire object in update, but only update modified properties. Also we have lots of serialisation and auditing code that uses EntityObject.

Since poco does create a proxy with EntityObject, we want our classes to be derived from EntityObject. We don't want proxy. We also heavily use CreateSourceQuery. The only problem is EDMX file and its big connection string syntax web.config.

Is there any way I can get rid of EDMX file? It will be useful as we can dynamically compile new class based on reverse engineering database.

I would also like to use DbContext with EntityObject instead of poco.

Internal Logic

---

1. Access Modified Properties in Save Changes which is available in ObjectStateEntry and Save them onto Audit with Old and New Values
2. Most of times we need to only check for Any condition on Navigation Property for example

---

```
 User.EmailAddresses.CreateSourceQuery()
   .Any( x=> x.EmailAddress == givenAddress);
```

---

1. Access Property Attributes, such as XmlIgnore etc, we rely heavily on attributes defined on the properties.

Comment: Can you add an example of what your customized properties look like?

Answer (score 4):

A proxy for a POCO is a dynamically created class which *derives from* (inherits) a POCO. It adds functionality previously found in `EntityObject`, namely lazy loading and change tracking, as long as a POCO meets [requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). A POCO or its proxy does not contain an `EntityObject` as the question suggests, but rather a proxy contains functionality of `EntityObject`. You cannot (AFAIK) use ModelBuilder with EntityObject derivatives and you cannot get to an underlying EntityObject from a POCO or a proxy, since there isn't one as such.

I don't know what features of `ObjectContext` does your existing serialisation and auditing code use, but  you can get to `ObjectContext` from a `DbContext` by casting a `DbContext` to a `IObjectContextAdapter` and accessing `IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext` property.

**EDIT:**

*1. Access Modified Properties in Save Changes which is available in ObjectStateEntry and Save them onto Audit with Old and New Values*

You can achieve this with POCOs by using `DbContext.ChangeTracker`. First you call `DbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges` to detect the changes (if you use proxies this is not needed, but can't hurt) and then you use `DbCotnext.Entries.Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged && e.State != EntityState.Detached)` to get `DbEntityEntry` list of changed entities for auditing. Each `DbEntityEntry` has `OriginalValues` and `CurrentValues` and the actual Entity is in property `Entity`.

You also have access to `ObjectStateEntry`, see below.

*2. Most of times we need to only check for Any condition on Navigation Property for example:*

```
User.EmailAddresses.CreateSourceQuery().Any( x=> x.EmailAddress == givenAddress);
```

You can use CreateSourceQuery() with DbContext by utilizing IObjectContextAdapter as described previously. When you have ObjectContext you can get to the source query for a related end like this:

```
public static class DbContextUtils
{
    public static ObjectQuery<TMember> CreateSourceQuery<TEntity, TMember>(this IObjectContextAdapter adapter, TEntity entity, Expression<Func<TEntity, ICollection<TMember>>> memberSelector) where TMember : class
    {
        var objectStateManager = adapter.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
        var objectStateEntry = objectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity);
        var relationshipManager = objectStateManager.GetRelationshipManager(entity);
        var entityType = (EntityType)objectStateEntry.EntitySet.ElementType;
        var navigationProperty = entityType.NavigationProperties[(memberSelector.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name];
        var relatedEnd = relationshipManager.GetRelatedEnd(navigationProperty.RelationshipType.FullName, navigationProperty.ToEndMember.Name);

        return ((EntityCollection<TMember>)relatedEnd).CreateSourceQuery();
    }        
}
```

This method uses no dynamic code and is strongly typed since it uses expressions. You use it like this:

```
myDbContext.CreateSourceQuery(invoice, i => i.details);
```

Comment: Problem is accessing CreateSourceQuery and ObjectStateEntry.

Comment: @AkashKava: Ok, updated the answer. In the proposed `CreateSourceQuery()` you have an example of how to access `ObjectStateEntry`.

Comment: Thanks, I will and will award the bounty once I get it working.

Comment: Hi, one last question, what about CreateSourceQuery for One to Zero or One property? In earlier version we were able to Object.NavigationPropertyReference.Load() or Object.NavigationPropertyReference.CreateSourceQuery()

Comment: @AkashKava Use the same code as above, just change the last line to not cast to `EntityCollection<TMember>` but to `EntityReference<TMember>`. Also, the method param is now not `Expression<Func<TEntity, ICollection<TMember>>> memberSelector` but `Expression<Func<TEntity, TMember>> memberSelector`

Comment: @AkashKava That `EntityReference<TMember>` is the same as your `Object.NavigationPropertyReference`, so you can Load(), CreateSourceQuery(), etc.